# AngularJS - .Get requests caching API output

Tags: angularjs, ajax, google-chrome

I have a strange problem.

I am working on a frontend for an application in AngularJS, there was a bug on the API which we patched.  However, my AngularJS call is still getting the old data that the API output before the fix.

If I browse to that API endpoint in chrome I get the correct output, however, when looking at the network tab in developer tools for my application the response is the old one.  I have tried restarting chrome, my computer, the api...everything.  I have cleared and disabled cache.

When I restart chrome, the first time the application loads it gets the correct output, but then every time after that it gets the old info.

Is there some kind of caching that I am not aware of?

Comment: No there is no caching until and unless you have implemented it yourself. Just for the sake of reverifying, you should check the api endpoint url used by frontend application and the actual endpoint url.

Comment: I literally copy and paste the url from the network tab into a new chrome tab and the chrome tab will show the correct output.

Interestingly when I check the network tab of chrome on the pure request, even though what is displayed in the tab is correct, what is displayed in the network tab of developer tools is the old one.

Seems more of a chrome issue but I can't figure it out....still happens in incognito.

Comment: I follow the practice of appending the random number at the end of URL. 
e.g. `/user?rand=Math.random()`

Comment: tahnks - didn't help :(  I have found it is happening in FF too

Comment: @MatthewDolman, i had this problem too, try to version your requests and files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to version your requests, files (Html and js), change version after each publish, and do not use `time` to version, it's will destroy the user cache, it be better if you use `date` that helps you to update cache just every day not every.

> use `version` as public variable that helps you to change it from 1 place.

it's so **important** to *version files and requests* to stay update for your clients

```
var version = "0.0.1"; //change version after each publish
//do not use time to version, it's will destroy the user cache
$http.get("api/getUsers?v=" + version).then(function(response){
   //your data solved
})
//for your states and all files you have
templateUrl: "partials/index.html?v=" + version
```